# Solr Query with hyphen return Zero Result

Tags: solr

I have a index document that look like this:

```
{"id:"abcde-efgr-jhik","domain": "http://www.play-bugs.com/index.com}
```

on the Domain field, I use text_general as data type.

I trying to query this document use

```
q=domain:play-bugs
```

it wont return any result, however if I use

```
q=domain:play-bugs.com
```

it give me the result as expected. I have tried to use "/" on the "-" char but no luck.

edit:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Comment: Can you post your _text_general_ fieldType definition ?

Comment: @EricLavault I'm adding it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior when using Solr's [Standard Tokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/tokenizers.html#standard-tokenizer).

> This tokenizer splits the text field into tokens, treating whitespace
>   and punctuation as delimiters. Delimiter characters are discarded,
>   with the following exceptions:
>
> - Periods (dots) that are not followed by whitespace are kept as part of
>     the token, including Internet domain names.
> - The "@" character is among the set of token-splitting punctuation, so
>     email addresses are not preserved as single tokens.
>
> Note that words are split at hyphens.

When `text_general` receives the content of `domain` from the input stream, it is tokenized like this :

- `http://www.play-bugs.com/index.com   =>   http | www.play |`**`bugs.com`**`| index.com`
- `play-bugs                            =>   play | bugs`
- `play-bugs.com                        =>   play |`**`bugs.com`**

You can see that `play-bugs.com` can match `bugs.com` while `play-bugs` can't, because a dot is not considered as a delimiter when not followed by a whitespace. There is no token `"bugs"` in the index so you won't match it even with the query `q=domain:bugs`.

You can try to use another tokenizer that also splits on dots, or add a filter like the [Word Delimiter Graph Filter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterGraphFilter)  to properly split the generated tokens.